# Убрать перенос текста

Tags: html, css

Почему-то не появляется троеточие в конце текста, а сам текст переносится на новую строку. Как это убрать?

```
<div class="block">
  <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/195-flat-flag-psd-icons/70/Russia.png">
  <a href="#russia">Российская Федерация</a>
</div>

.block {
    width: 200px;
}
.block img {
      position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 24px;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
.block a {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 85%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    color: #507299;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mpg2d00o/2/

Comment: Хм, у меня троеточие появляется и сам текст НЕ переносится на новую строку...

Comment: @Ep1demic в JSFiddle всё наглядно показано.

Comment: В том то и дело! Вы пишите "Почему-то не появляется троеточие в конце текста, а сам текст переносится на новую строку." А я вам и говорю, что у меня в JSFiddle - все окей, троеточие ПОЯВЛЯЕТСЯ, а текст НЕ переносится.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin У меня тоже нет многоточия, вы в каком браузере смотрите?

Comment: `.block {
    max-width: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}` и все работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте изображение внутрь ссылки:

```html
    <div class="block">
      <a href="#russia">
      <img src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/195-flat-flag-psd-icons/70/Russia.png">
      Российская Федерация
      </a>
    </div>
```

либо добавьте внешнему диву стили для обрезания и уберите их со ссылки:

```
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

а то получается, что вы запрещаете перенос внутри ссылки, а изображение находится за ее пределами и поэтому происходит перенос.